# Перевести числа

Tags: c#

У меня есть число допустим `12865` мне нужно его перевести в `12,865`.
Тоесть если число больше тысячи переводить его в такой формат, но если число меньше тысячи то оставить таким как есть.

Comment: Число  это число, а то, что вы говорите, это формат перевода числа в строку, ищите [тут](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/standard-numeric-format-strings) или [тут](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-numeric-format-strings).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Microsoft Docs: [Standard Numeric Format Strings](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/standard-numeric-format-strings)

> N" or "n"
>   Result: Integral and decimal digits, group separators, and a decimal separator with optional negative sign.
>   1234.567 ("N", en-US) -> 1,234.57
>   1234.567 ("N", ru-RU) -> 1 234,57
>   1234 ("N1", en-US) -> 1,234.0
>   1234 ("N1", ru-RU) -> 1 234,0
>   -1234.56 ("N3", en-US) -> -1,234.560
>   -1234.56 ("N3", ru-RU) -> -1 234,560

Соответственно, для вашего случая(разделение разрядов запятыми) код будет следующим:

```
int number = 123456789;
string formattedNumber = number.ToString("N0", CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("en-US"));
```

Результат:

```
123,456,789
```

Answer (score -1):

```
        string ToStringWithSeparator(int num, string separator)
        {
            return Enumerable.Range(0, 10)
                .Select(x => new string(num.ToString()
                    .Reverse()
                    .Skip(x * 3)
                    .Take(3)
                    .Reverse()
                    .ToArray()))
                .Reverse()
                .SkipWhile(x => string.IsNullOrEmpty(x))
                .Reverse()
                .Aggregate(string.Empty, (x, a) => $"{a}{separator}{x}");
        }
```